# unique with "with" operator in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am a new SystemVerilog user and I have faced a strange (from my point of view) behavior of combination of unique method called for fixed array with `with` operator.

```
module test();
  int arr[12] = '{1,2,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,10,8};
  int q[$]
  initial begin
    q = arr.unique() with (item > 5 ? item : 0);
    $display("the result is %p",q);
  end
```

I've expected to get queue {8,9,10} but instead I have got {1,8,9,10}.

Why there is a one at the index 0 ?

Comment: I found out that on position of 1 can be any number. For example I have tested a array int arr[] = '{0,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,10,8}; and the result was {0,8,9,10}. It seems to me that there is a some reason to return the first element of the array with unique method, but steel not obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to combine the operation of the `find` method with `unique`. Unfortunately, it does not work the way you expect. `unique` returns the element, not the expression in the `with` clause, which is 0 for elements 1,2,3,4 and 5. The simulator could have chosen any of those elements to represent the unique value for 0(and different simulators do pick different values)

You need to write them separately:

```
module test();
  int arr[$] = '{1,2,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,10,8};
  int q[$]
  initial begin
    arr = arr.find() with (item > 5);
    q = arr.unique();
    $display("the result is %p",q);
  end
```

### Update explaining the original results

The `with` clause generates a list of values to check for uniqueness

```
'{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,9,10,10,8};
  ^.            ^ ^ ^
```

Assuming the simulator chooses the first occurrence of a replicated value to remain, then it returns `{arr[0], arr[7], arr[8], arr[9]}` from the original array, which is `{1,8,9,10}`

Comment: I tried to answer this myself and would have suggested separating the expression into two (because that worked), but didn't answer because I didn't understand why one expression wasn't working. Unfortunately, I still don't. Please could you expand a bit?

Comment: Added detailed explanation